# webpack is trying to parse sass into javascript in isomorphic app

Tags: webpack, sass

I am getting the following error:

```
/Users/paulcowan/projects/cake-manager/node_modules/@cutting/component-library/dist/components/atoms/Input/Input.scss:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { @import '../../../styles/index';
                                                              ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:152:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:624:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/paulcowan/projects/cake-manager/node_modules/@cutting/component-library/src/components/atoms/Input/index.tsx:4:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
```

My css rules look like this:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.(css|scss|sass)$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'css-loader/locals',
          options: {
            modules: true,
            importLoaders: 2,
            getLocalIdent
          }
        },
        {
          loader: 'sass-loader'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
```

it looks like some loader is trying to turn the sass into javascript but I do not understand why.  I don't use babel and use typescript with this configuration:

```
{
  test: /\.tsx?$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
  options: merge({ useBabel: false, useCache: false }, typescriptOptions)
}
```

])

What would be trying to parse the sass into js?

It only happens when I have a dependency in node_modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody else struggling with this problem, the answer for me was to add an entry to my [nodeExternals](https://github.com/liady/webpack-node-externals) hash.

My `nodeExternals` now looks like this:

```
nodeExternals({
      modulesDir,
      whitelist: [
        isDevelopment ? 'webpack/hot/poll?300' : null,
        /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|otf)$/,
        /\.(svg|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/,
        /\.(mp4|mp3|ogg|swf|webp)$/,
        /\.(css|scss|sass|sss|less)$/,
        /^@cutting/
      ].filter(x => x)
    });
```

I added the `/^@cutting/` entry to the whitelist array and now everything magically works.